# Can't Display Records from Ember.js Data in Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to show records from the Ember.js data store in the my template. In my controller I have the following code:

```
orders: null,
```

[...]

```
openOrderModal: function(name) {
  $('.ui.' + name + '.modal').modal('show');
  var orders = this.get('store').peekAll('orders');
  console.log(orders);
  this.set('orders', orders);
},
```

I peek all records from the data store and save it to a variable. 
In the template i have a loop. But it doesn't work.

```
{{#each orders as |order|}}
  {{order.id}} {{order.supply_id}}
{{/each}}
```

Can you help me?

Kind regards

Comment: _What_ exactly does not work? Can you confirm the function is called? If so, is it logging the expected orders? Does anything else from the modal show up? (And why is that `$('...` there?)

Comment: I peek a other model. And it worked. I think the problem is that the records in the Ember data store are green colored in the Ember inspector. They are not saved

Comment: When I try: 
this.get('store').peekAll('orders').findBy('isNew', true);
the array  "orders" is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peekAll` only returns records that are already in the store. If you did not load any orders elsewhere (like in your route, where records should be loaded) it will return an empty list. [It should include unsaved, just created records](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.15.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/peekAll?anchor=peekAll) of the appropriate model, however.

`findAll` is the method to make the store make API calls, but returns a promise, i.e. you have to deal with the retrieved records in the `then` method (unless you load them in your route's `model` hook, returned promises will be dealt with appropriately).